# Convert Json encoded data to javascript array and access value by index

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax-request

I am getting json response from ajax like this

```
  echo  json_encode($data);
```

Ajax code:

```
  $.ajax({
        url:"PaymentSlip/check", 
        data:{val:val},
        type: 'POST',
        success:function(ajaxresult)
        {
            $("#jgoli").html(ajaxresult);
        }
    });
```

Result I am getting is:

```
     [{"paymentId":"2","paymentLabNo":"MR-622-040618",paymentTestId":"1"}]
```

Now I want to access my json array in javascript by index like

```
      ajaxresult[0] = 2; i.e paymentId=2
      ajaxresult[1] = 2; i.e paymentLabNo=MR-622-040618
```

How would I achieve that?

Note: I have tried many examples on stackoverflow, I know this question must have answered earlier. But I am still stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve - you want to print, on to the web page, the JSON data but in the format you used as an example? Or are you just trying to parse the data and don't understand how to access the data at all?

Comment: Yes, I want to print the data on the web page by index i.e. ajax result['paymentId'] which in my question equals to '2'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data =  [{"paymentId":"2","paymentLabNo":"MR-622-040618","paymentTestId":"1"}];
    //Loop on the object as key=>value
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
    //And diplay it in the result div
        $('#result').append('<p>'+data[key]['paymentId']+'</p>');
        $('#result').append('<p>'+data[key]['paymentLabNo']+'</p>');
         $('#result').append('<p>'+data[key]['paymentTestId']+'</p>');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are getting is a string of encoded JSON, to use it as an object you must parse it.

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: ok, I parsed the json response. Now how can I access the parsed data by index?

Comment: eval() should be avoided at all costs. There are other safer methods for parsing a string to a JSON object.

Comment: You obtain an object using the mthod from above. You can iterate between the values using a code like this `for( key in obj) {
if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key) ) 
console.log(key + " is " + obj[key])

}`

Comment: Yeah you should use JSON.parse as the answer states. You can use something like `var obj = JSON.parse(ajaxresult)` and then access it like `obj[0]`

Comment: solved the problem by above answer. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.get("ajax_call.php", function(data){
        //console.log(data);
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        $.each(result, function(key, value){

            $('#data').append('<tr><td>'+result[key]['username']+'</td><td>'+result[key]['email']+'</td><td>'+result[key]['mobile']+'</td></tr>');
            console.log(result[key])

        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $.ajax({
        url:"PaymentSlip/check", 
        data:{val:val},
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: "json", // add this
        success:function(ajaxresult)
        {
            // access return results as
            //ajaxresult[0].paymentId;
            //ajaxresult[0].paymentLabNo;
            //ajaxresult[0].paymentTestId;
            //$("#jgoli").html(ajaxresult);
        }
    });
```

Comment: solved the problem by above answer. Thanks for your time.